# How to extract number from html tags in Alteryx?

Tags: regex, alteryx

I have a scraped dataset that contains a column of data like below:

```
<td>1,968</td>
<td>185</td>
<td>1,285<sup id="cite_ref-4" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-4">[4]</a></sup></td>
```

I am using [Alteryx](http://www.alteryx.com/) to process the data and I want to use regex to extract the number between the html tags `<td>` and `</td>`. So in the above case, I am supposed to get back 1968, 185 and 1285. I tried the following regular expressions, but neither worked [using this tester](http://www.regexpal.com/). I believe the version of regex should be R for Alteryx, but not sure.

```
>([0-9]+)<

>[0-9]+<
```

Can someone please shed some light on this? Thanks!

Comment: `library(rvest); '<td>1,968</td>
<td>185</td>
<td>1,285<sup id="cite_ref-4" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-4">[4]</a></sup></td>' %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('td') %>% html_text() %>% readr::parse_number()`

Comment: because http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4497050

Comment: R has different regex flavors depending on the package and additional arguments. Saying that the "version of regex should be R" does not clarify anything here. [Docs say](https://help.alteryx.com/9.5/RegEx.htm) it is Boost. R does not support Boost. I removed the R tag.

Comment: I think you need to use [`>([0-9][0-9,]*)<`](https://regex101.com/r/YnWPj3/1) with [*`Tokenize`* function](https://help.alteryx.com/9.5/RegEx.htm#Tokenize).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate Alteryx approach: use a Formula tool to remove `<td>` as well as commas and spaces, then use a Select tool to cast what remains to the numeric type of your choice... it will automatically take everything up to the first non-numeric character.

Comment: This is interesting. Can you pls share the formula to use? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming a field `[f1]`, the following uses `Replace` three times to remove the three items I mentioned: `Replace(Replace(Replace([f1], "<td>", ""),",","")," ","") `